# Google Sheets App Script While Loop won't stop iterating?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, while-loop, iteration

I'm trying to locate a row number using a while loop, i thought this would be pretty basic to do as you can iterate until the criteria is met, i've got the value i'm trying to find set as a variable and i thought a while loop would iterate through all the options until it reaches my criteria, and then return the value of i (which represents the row number in this instance)
Trouble is, using the logger i'm able to see that it finds the result i'm after and then continues to iterate, is anyone able to help?
Would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Labour');
  var i = 3;
  var values = sheet2.getRange(i,3).getValue();
  ///Logger.log(values);
  var value = sheet.getRange(2,11).getValue();
  ///Logger.log(value);
  while(values != value){
   /// Logger.log(i);
   /// Logger.log(values);
    i = i +1;
    values = sheet2.getRange(i,3).getValue();
    }
  return i;
    
  }
```

Comment: In order to correctly replicate your situation of `Trouble is, using the logger i'm able to see that it finds the result i'm after and then continues to iterate`, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image?

Comment: my apologies, it's input is a date (week commencing mondays date) and it's trying to find the same date on another sheet, so that i can use the value of i as the row number to write data to in another function

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your actual situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> it's input is a date (week commencing mondays date) and it's trying to find the same date on another sheet, so that i can use the value of i as the row number to write data to in another function

I thought that in your situation, the cell values might be the date object. I thought that when the cell value is the date object, your issue might occur. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. So in the case of Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script, I think that the following 2 patterns can be used for comparing the cell values of the date object.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the cell values of the date object are converted to the unix time and those are compared.

```js
function sample1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Labour');
  var i = 3;
  var values = sheet2.getRange(i, 3).getValue().getTime();
  var value = sheet.getRange(2, 11).getValue().getTime();
  while (values != value) {
    i = i + 1;
    values = sheet2.getRange(i, 3).getValue().getTime();
  }
  return i;
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the cell values of the date object are converted to the string value as the displayed value.

```js
function sample2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Labour');
  var i = 3;
  var values = sheet2.getRange(i, 3).getDisplayValue();
  var value = sheet.getRange(2, 11).getDisplayValue();
  while (values != value) {
    i = i + 1;
    values = sheet2.getRange(i, 3).getDisplayValue();
  }
  return i;
}
```

#### Pattern 3:

In your script, `getValue` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. So I thought that your script might be able to be modified as follows.

```js
function sample3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Labour');
  var value = sheet.getRange(2, 11).getValue().getTime();
  var values = sheet2.getRange(3, 3, sheet2.getLastRow() - 2).getValues();
  var i = values.findIndex(([c]) => c.getTime() == value) + 3;
  return i;
}
```

and

```js
function sample4() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Labour');
  var value = sheet.getRange(2, 11).getDisplayValue();
  var values = sheet2.getRange(3, 3, sheet2.getLastRow() - 2).getDisplayValues();
  var i = values.findIndex(([c]) => c == value) + 3;
  return i;
}
```

#### Note:

- From your replying, I supposed that your cell values might be the date object. By this, I proposed the above modifications. So when your actual Spreadsheet is not the date object, it might be required to modify the script. When you tested the above scripts and it is not the result you expect, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: is it normal for the getTime() to present an error? It says it's not a valid function, i believe this is due to not declaring it as a date?

Comment: So after playing around with your solutions, the getDisplayValue() worked, however getTime() provided an error "function not available" and the findIndex() didn't work either  as C was not declared, thank you for helping me find a solution!

Comment: @br4dl3y Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I asked about the sample input and output situations, you said `it's input is a date (week commencing mondays date) and it's trying to find the same date on another sheet, so that i can use the value of i as the row number to write data to in another function`. By this, I proposed a modified script as your values are the date object.

Comment: @br4dl3y But from `is it normal for the getTime() to present an error? It says it's not a valid function, i believe this is due to not declaring it as a date?` and `So after playing around with your solutions, the getDisplayValue() worked, however getTime() provided an error "function not available" and the findIndex() didn't work either as C was not declared, thank you for helping me find a solution!`, it is considered that your values are not the date object.

Comment: @br4dl3y In that case, I think that in order to correctly replicate your situation, it is required to check your sample Spreadsheet. So can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the current script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't share a sample script from my work e-mail with the data on it, is there a way to impliment it into the question? I've resolved the issue using the .getDisplayValue() function and works correctly!

Comment: @br4dl3y Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: The issue is resolved, here is the code i used                                                               var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Labour');
  var i = 3;
  var values = sheet2.getRange(i, 4).getDisplayValue();
  //Logger.log(values);
  var value = sheet.getRange(2, 11).getDisplayValue();
  //Logger.log(value);
  while (values != value) {
    i = i + 1;
    values = sheet2.getRange(i, 4).getDisplayValue();
    //Logger.log(values)
  }
  //Logger.log(i);
  return i;
  
}

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add .getDisplayValues() after .getRange to read the time/date as a time/date instead of a formula